# facebook javascript sdk not posting via ajax using fb.api and .post

Tags: facebook, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook application.  The users are logged in and authorized.  I am calling fb.api to post the user's name to my textfile. The alert shows the name. The post doesn't seem to post to my aspx file..

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (href, widget) {
    alert("outside");
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        alert(response.name);
        var paramsObj = { 'name': response.name };
        $.post("ajax/delete.aspx", paramsObj);
    });
    window.location.replace("Default.aspx");
});
```

I've updated my code to include showing the encapsulating facebook calls to give a broader picture as well as to include @Lix changes [thank you!].

Comment: Try Firebug and keep an eye on the "Net" tab.

Comment: tried that... the post is literally not being posted...

Comment: 1) you don't have to wrap your keys with quotes. 2) try removing the alerts 3) try commenting the `window.location.replace(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page was being redirected prior to the api call/ajax post. This is what worked:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (href, widget) { 
    FB.api('/me', function (response) { 
        var paramsObj = { 'name': response.name }; 
        $.post("ajax/delete.aspx", paramsObj);
        window.location.replace("Default.aspx"); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you might want to try :

1. Define your post parameters object before and only place the objects name in the jQuery $.post method.
2. Wrap your json keynames with quotes.

   `var paramsObj = { 'name':response.name};`
   `$.post("ajax/write.aspx", paramsObj );`
3. Use firebug/chrome developers tools to debug the AJAX request and see if any value is being passed and/or use breakpoints in your code to help you understand where the value is missing.